# why innodb lock the next row when i use <=?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

> ```
> my mysql env:
> innodb_version          | 5.5.30
> version                 | 5.5.30-log
> version_compile_machine | x86_64             
> version_compile_os      | Linux 
>
> tx_isolation = REPEATABLE-READ
> innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = OFF
> ```

```
I create a table A:
| A     | CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `i_name` (`name`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


mysql> select * from A;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  2 | new  |
|  7 | aa   |
|  8 | adf  |
|  9 | aa   |
| 11 | a    |
| 12 | bbb  |
+----+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

when I use the sql:
    begin;
    select * from A where id<=2 for update;

I find this sql can lock the next row id=7:

```
TABLE LOCK table `test`.`A` trx id 2F06 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 420 n bits 80 index `PRIMARY` of table `test`.`A` trx id 2F06 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000007; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000077f; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex ef000001750128; asc     u (;;
 3: len 2; hex 6161; asc aa;;

Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000002ef1; asc     . ;;
 2: len 7; hex 1f0000020e0110; asc        ;;
 3: len 3; hex 6e6577; asc new;;
```

i don't know why? i think the primary key index can find the uniq key 2 .